# Trigger click event of dynamic loaded content from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Unable to trigger click event for an dynamically loaded content from ajax call. Tried to use trigger method but guess I am missing something here.

```
$("#call-setup").on("click", function () {
        var $this = $("#settings")
        var url = $this.data("link")

        loadwifinetworks(url);
        //$("#connectivity").trigger("click")
    });

    async function loadwifinetworks(url) {
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
            $.get(url, function (context) {
                $("#contentArea").html(context);
                resolve("success")
            });

        });
        //$('body').find('#connectivity').trigger('click');
        // $('#contentArea').find('#connectivity').trigger("click")

    }
```

Comment: Call `trigger()` ***inside*** the `$.get()` callback. You're doing it too early in all the commented out lines.

Comment: Multiple issues here `$this` is undefined and would never be equal to a new jQuery object if it was. `$.get` returns a promise already so wrapping in `new Promise` is an anti-pattern. The `on('click'` is always going to return `id="call-setup"` as `this`